# When is 'this' not an instance of the defining function?

Tags: javascript, new-operator, instanceof

I am trying to understand the following piece of Javascript code:

```
var Query = function(config, values, callback) {

  // use of "new" optional
  if(!(this instanceof Query)) { return new Query(config, values, callback); }

  ...

};
```

If someone calls `new Query(...)`, when and why `this` would not be an instance of Query? Why does this code tests this possibility? What issue does it solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is JavaScript pattern known as "Self-Invoking Constructor" (check [JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do)).

If the function `Query` is called:

```
Query();
```

then `this` won't be instance of Query.
The code makes sure that no matter how `Query` is called new object, created with the constructor function `Query`, will be returned.

For example:

```
function foo() {
}

console.log(foo());           //undefined
console.log(foo.call(null));  //undefined
console.log(foo.apply(null)); //undefined
console.log(new foo());       //object, instance of foo
```

but if:

```
function foo() {
  if (!(this instanceof foo)) {
    return new foo();
  }
}

console.log(foo());           //object, instance of foo
console.log(foo.call(null));  //object, instance of foo
console.log(foo.apply(null)); //object, instance of foo
console.log(new foo());       //object, instance of foo
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is only preventing a bug that could arise if somebody forgets to add `new` : it works the same in that case.

I've frequently seen this pattern. In my opinion it's bad : you shouldn't try to prevent bad misuses of your API, especially as it might make the user code more obscure for somebody who knows `new`. It's not like if `new` were an especially advanced JavaScript feature... It's better to fail than to let various seemingly invalid user codes be magically valid.

Comment: I agree with your comment on using new, but rather than taking the risk of letting the code crash in production, I'd rather implement a failsafe if statement and log a warn/debug statement saying new should be used. My general philosophy is to protect the application in prod, but not everyone has to agree with this.

Comment: Your code is probably at least a little tested. When somebody writes `Query('a')` and it doesn't work, it will add the `new`.

Comment: Yes testing is key (the if is not a substitute to testing), but people do make mistakes, even unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

this code makes it possible to use Query constructor with `new` and without `new` statements, if you will use

```
var bla = Query();
```

`this` will poing to `window`, it'll be checked inside the `Query` function and `new Query()` will be called, this time `this instanceof Query` will return true